# "DeviceMotion" Event ref invalid - Error when running ARKit Application

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I've looked around on stackoverflow and the internet and was not able to find a good answer for the following error when running the ARKit application:

> [DeviceMotion] Event ref invalid

Does anyone know what the problem is and what I should be fixing?